# Does a person with awakened kundalini stay in moksha state?

Tags: moksha, kundalini

We know that a jivanmukta is in moksha state.

But is it true that a person whose kundalini is awakened is in moksha state?

Comment: No, just awakened Kundalini does not imply the moksha state. One has to pierce all the chakras and energise them. Then one has to activate the Sahasrara Chakra fully to reach the moksha state.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Oh! I mean who totally crossed all levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be said so.

Because when the power of Kundalini is awakened, all the Chakras are gradually pierced and become active.

> Supta ghuruprasadena yada jagharti kundali
>  Tada sarvani padmani
>   bhidyante ghranthayoapi cha ||
>
> When the sleeping Kundalinî awakens by favour of a guru, then all the
>   lotuses (in the six chakras or centres) and all the knots are pierced
>   through.
>
> **HYP 3.2**

And, such a person, whose Kundalini Shakti is awakened, goes to Samadhi every now and then.

> Utpannaśaktibodhasya tyaktanihśeshakarmanah
>  Yoghinah sahajāvasthā
>   svayameva prajāyate ||
>
> The Yogî whose śakti has awakened, and who has renounced all actions,
>   attains to the condition of Samâdhi, without any effort

In such a person the Prana remains absorb in the Shunya state which is the same thing as saying that the person has attained the Samadhi state.

> Vividhairasanaih kumbhairvichitraih karanairapi
>  Prabuddhayam
>   mahasaktau pranah sunye praliyate ||
>
> By means of various postures and different Kumbhakas, when the great
>   power (Kundalî) awakens, then the Prâna becomes absorbed in Sûnya
>   (Samâdhi).
>
> **HYP 4.10**

And, these words Shunya, Samadhi, Moksha/Jivanmukti describe the same state.

> Rajayogah samadhischa unmani cha manonmani
>  Amaratvam layastattvam
>   sunyasunyam param padam
>  Amanaskam tathadvaitam niralambam
>   nirañjanam
>  Jivanmuktischa sahaja turya chetyekavachakah||
>
> Raja Yogî, **Samâdhi**, Unmani, mauonmanî, Amarativa, Laya, Tatwa,
>   **Sûnya**, Asûnya, Parama Pada, Amanaska, Adwaitama, Nirãlamba, Nirañjana, **Jîwana mukti**, Sahajâ, Turyâ, are all synonymous.
>
> **HYP 4.3,4**

Therefore, such a person is indeed a Jivanmukta.

(HYP denotes Hatha Yoga Pradipika).

Comment: The awakening does not guarantee either the attainment or jivamukta. It is only the beginning...

Answer (score 2):

It is correct that one who reaches the state of Samadhi (Kundalini awakened state), he already liberated even if he is alive.

In Shiva Sutra [Section 3 Sutra 18](http://bibleoteca.narod.ru/tantra/Jaideva_Singh_Siva_Sutras.pdf), it is said:

> "So long as Suddha vidya does not disappear, the possibility
>   of another birth for him vanishes completely."

Similar thing has been expressed in [Swachhanda Tantra(Shiva Sutras Page 169)](http://bibleoteca.narod.ru/tantra/Jaideva_Singh_Siva_Sutras.pdf) as well:

> स्वनिर्वाणं परम शुद्धं गुरूपारंपरागतम्।
>   तद्वदित्वा विमुच्येत गत्वा भूयो न जायते।।
>
> "One's liberation acquired through a tradition of spiritual
>   teachers is excellent and pure. Having realized it, **one becomes
>   liberated while alive, and after passing away from the world is
>   not born again."**